# How does github finds If two branches has conflict before actually merging them?

Tags: git, github, merge-conflict-resolution

In the pull request option. Upon selecting two branch, github notifies if the two branches has any conflict. What is the command to find branch conflict?

Comment: damn this guy has a great post on this: https://code-maven.com/git-check-for-conflicts-before-merge

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[git merge-tree](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge-tree)

To compute the merge results of 2 revisions without making real changes:

```
git merge-tree $(git merge-base <rev1> <rev2>) <rev1> <rev2>
```

The 2 revisions have at least 1 common ancestor. If there're conflicts, the marks like `<<<<<<<`, `=======`, `>>>>>>>` will be printed.

Update: for binary file conflicts, the log includes lines like

```
warning: Cannot merge binary files: <binary path> (.our .vs .their)
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you want to check for conflict of 'dev' branch merging into the 'master' branch, then first check out to the 'master' branch and then use the merge command as mentioned below:

```
$ git checkout master
$ git merge branch2 --no-ff --no-commit
```

There's complex logic that goes into checking for merge conflict, but cut short it compares all the newly committed files from the ***'last merged commit'*** line by line and if there's a change in the same line in both of the branches it will mark it as conflict, as git doesn't know which one to pick.

Comment: I found this answer before. I guess i have to manually abort the merge after running the command you mentioned. Thanks for the reply